# Gridview button Click - Populate user control, then open a Jquery dialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview, modal-dialog

I have a gridview of users.

What I *WANT* to happen:

When someone wants to edit a user's details, they click on the relevant gridview button, and a Jquery modal dialog opens up with the user information pre-populated.

The Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                //setup new User dialog
                $('#divEditUser').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    draggable: true,
                    width: 650,
                    modal: true,
                    title: "Edit User",
                    open: function (type, data) {
                        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                    }
                });
```

Gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' CommandName="EditUser" Text="Edit User" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The custom user control:

```
<div id="divEditUser" title="Edit user">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenUserID" runat="server" />
    <cac:UserDetails runat="server" ID="UserDetails" />
    <asp:Button id="btnSaveChanges" Text="Save Changes" runat="server" />
</div>
```

The Code Behind:

```
protected void gridUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.CommandName == "EditUser")
        {
            Button btn = (Button)e.CommandSource;               // the button
            GridViewRow myRow = (GridViewRow)btn.Parent.Parent;  // the row
            GridView myGrid = (GridView)sender; // the gridview
            string ID = myGrid.DataKeys[myRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            UserDetails.PopulateUser(Convert.ToInt16(ID));

            THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO OPEN THE DIALOG 
        }
    }
```

My problem is that  the dialog box appears & disappears on the postback, or it just won't display, or it will display on the popup (not populated) and again on the form (populated)

I've tried `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`

I've also tried several `OnClientClick` methods.
I've tried with  update panels, without update panels

but again & again,  no luck.

Has anyone actually achieved this ?
...And would you share the code - please ?

Answer (score 0):

use return false statement in your jquery dialog function

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer?  At this point this is basically a comment not an answer.